# How do I align this text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the text look like this:

```
here goes a nice image.
some text | a small ico
```

I also wanto to the text below the image, plus the separator and the icon must be same size as in the image.

Currently it look like this:

```
here goes a nice image.
some text 
| 
a small ico
```

I don't know they are below of each other because I'm using col-md* inside a row. How do I fix this?

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <img src="http://www.foranyinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/motorbike_black_yamaha_r6_74416_3840x2400.jpg" style="width:128;height:128px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
             <span class="name">A Beutiful star</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div style="width:32px;height:32px">
                <div class="verticalBar"></div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/rate-star-button_318-76714.jpg" style="width:32px; height:32px" />
        </div>
    </div>
     </div>
```

**css:**

```
.verticalBar {
    border-left:1px solid green;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use a table.

Comment: @Jay:- Check the `Live example`!

Comment: This is what `float:right;` was made for.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? I don't see any references in your Fiddler to it, although I see classes like col-md-4...

Comment: @Jay: The HTML is in the post...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Even with bootstrap?

Comment: @Vi100: Yes, I'm. I forget to add it to fiddler. I'll remove it anyway

Answer (score 1):

can you add following style for inner div's,

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11415444)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` to `.row` to make as per your expected result.

```
.row {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s24hyyk4/4/)**

And add bootstrap plugins in your fiddle.